# What is a word for people yet to respond?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am writing a blog post for a class, and need a word that describes all the students who have yet to post.

Something like:

Therefore I pose this question to (anyone who has not yet written their blog response): blahdy blahdy blah?

Comment: [*Disregarder*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Disregarder)? One who disregards or one who ignores.

Comment: In some workplaces, employees who have not completed a mandatory task (timesheet, self eval, training course) by a deadline are called *defaulters*.  However, in the context you describe, I highly recommend that you just remove the parentheses from your example and phrase it *exactly* like that.  Don't try to force it to one word.

Comment: Can you explain more about these people’s situation? Are they all supposed to post but some haven’t yet or is posting optional?  Is there a deadline for posting? Is it fair to assume that those who have not posted are observing the blog but just not participating? (Maybe: to all those *lurkers*??)

Comment: Now if we only had a future active participle in English, we could craft a verb form used as a noun adjectival compound term like [*morituri te salutamus* (Those who are about to die salute you)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Imperator,_morituri_te_salutant) and have *blogguturi* (those who are about to blog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Therefore I pose this question to **pending** bloggers

That is, using the word 'pending' as an **adjective** ...

From Mirriam-Webster: 'happening or likely to happen soon' (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pending)

From dictionary.com: 'about to take place; impending.'
(http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pending)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. Please consider adding objective sources to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not *[potential](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/potential)* bloggers?

> Having or showing the capacity to become or develop into something in the future:
>   *a two-pronged campaign to woo potential customers*

Similarly *[prospective](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prospective)*

> (Of a person) expected or expecting to be something particular in the future:
>   *she showed a prospective buyer around the house*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 0):

I think that for a Web site, **lurkers** might be the best option - it's jargon, though. Or you might try **bystanders**.

That said, I would not make too great an effort to find a single word.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are looking for something fairly concise.

**I pose this question to the as-yet uncommitted...**

I'm thinking of those who haven't yet responded to a poll.

When your students are used to this, you could leave out the "as-yet" part.

Answer (score 0):

What about the word *tardy?* As I understand it, the OP would like to remind the students that some of them have not yet submitted their contributions to the blog. So, the teacher might say to his/her class, "Would those of you who have been tardy in posting, please do so as soon as possible".

**Tardy** : Slow in moving, acting, or happening; arriving or doing something late.  **Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary**